# How to use quotes in Visual Studio Code settings values?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm trying to add this as my default terminal: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat" but how do I set the "/k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat" part in terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows settings. It doesn't allow for nested quotation marks. I tried escaping the quotation marks, double quotes etc.  Each option the command prompt states the path set is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

go to File menu > Preferences > workspace settings. On right hand side, you will see settings.json. In this file add below line-

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe  /k \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nodevars.bat\""
```

thats it. now you can run npm install and npm start commands to run your angular2 application.

see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think `\"` does not work for cmd shell args but this works for me:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat",
        "&&start-ssh-agent"
    ],
```